# PHP Accessing the user's country (locale)

Tags: php, locale, superglobals

Is there a superglobal reference to the user's country or is using  the IP against a database of IP to Country lookups the best way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wish there were such thing as `$_SERVER['HTTP_COUNTRY']`... maybe in php99 ? ;)
for the time being, http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php is your best bet

however, if you're only interested in user's language, there is `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]`

Comment: Funnily enough, some providers include the MaxMind GeoIP module in PHP which provides country information in the $_SERVER variable: http://www.maxmind.com/app/php - very, very rare, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more options for ip to country lookups

http://www.hostip.info/

http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Geo

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how to get country code from the IP. It's not a PHP superglobal, but it's not too had to implement either.

```
$country = strtoupper(file_get_contents("http://geoip.wtanaka.com/cc/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}"));
```