# get country name with php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IP to Country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/ip-to-country)

I am trying to get the country name with php by using

```
$country = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

it is working fine for me (returns US). But when I used it on my website, for most of my users it is returning XX and that is not a country code.
Is there any way I can get the country name with php ?
PLEASE HELP

Comment: FYI: not all IPs have geo mappings, or the api provider's restricting access to that country's data to for-pay service tiers.

Comment: What does $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] contain? Maybe that global variable isn't populating correctly due to some server configuration? For example, if I go to http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=0.0.0.0, I also get 'XX'.

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736024/php-accessing-the-users-country-locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [mod_geoip](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2), then you'll have access to the country name in `$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME']`

Comment: Good idea. Also, there is a PECL library that connects to the same system as mod_geoip and adds new PHP functions to make calls to the country database. [Download](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip) / [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php)